# Combining 2 RDDs in python Spark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd, k-means

I have 2 RDDs. Assume rdd1 = {'a','b','c', 'a', 'c', 'a'} and rdd2 is an output of KMeans with cluster assignment as follows -> rdd2={0,0,1,1,1,0}. I want to eventually find out how many a's and b's are there in cluster 0 and 1. For example 0 has 2 a's so something like {0, a, 2} etc. Is there a way I combine these 2 RDDS to do such an operation?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: So to clarify, you'd be looking for {0/a/2}, {1/a/1}, {0/b/1}, {1/c/2}, is my understanding correct?

Comment: Yes that's correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below works. using `tuples` and `list` instead of `set` wherever appropriate.

```
rdd1 = sc.parallelize(['a','b','c', 'a', 'c', 'a'])
rdd2 = sc.parallelize([0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0])
rdd = rdd1.zip(rdd2).map(lambda x: (x,1)).reduceByKey(lambda x,y: x+y).map(lambda ((x1,x2),y): (x1,x2,y))
rdd.collect()
```

**Output:**

```
[('a', 0, 2), ('b', 0, 1), ('c', 1, 2), ('a', 1, 1)]
```

Comment: If this were a particularly large data set, you'd be better off using `reduceByKey` rather than `groupBy` followed by `map`.

Comment: @JoeC thanks for your suggestion. I have updated the answer

Comment: Thank you so much for your suggestion @JoeC.